# Drupal 7 adding jQuery to a Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I have been searching for a method to accomplish a goal for several days.

What I would like to do is use a jQuery library (flot) inside of a Drupal 7 Module that I have written.

Here is what I think I need to do and the reasons I am confused about implementing it.

1. include the flot library in the module folder.
   -I haven't found any information that suggests if this is the correct place to store the files.
2. Include the flot module some how in the module in one of the hook functions.
   -The resources I have found are not clear as to which hook function the module should be included from.
3. Write the associated jquery to display a chart using flot.
   -I think this should be done in the function where the page is described, but I can't find a tutorial or reference where this is done.

Thanks for any help clarifying this that you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I would include the flot files in a subdirectory of your module, to allow for easier updating. Alternately you could include instructions on how to download the files from the flot git repo.

If you plan to distribute this module on drupal.org, I believe that you should be able to re-license flot to be GPL, which is required to put the code in the Drupal repo ([source.](https://drupal.org/licensing/faq#q7))

Additionally, I would look at [the jQuery Plugin Module](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_plugin) as a reference of where to place jQuery plugin files inside your module directory structure.

Good luck!